# Android: set custom value to the NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I create a custom number picker and added to the layout by using layout inflater.
I want to set three values to the number picker 2,5,10. By using **setMinValue(1),setMaxValue(3)** it setting only 1 to 3 default number.

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    ((int) RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

            np.setLayoutParams(params);
            np.setMinValue(1);
            np.setMaxValue(3);
            np.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            np.setValue(2);
```

Instead of setting 1 to 3 , I want to set 2,5,10.
Can anyone please tell me how to set custom value in Number Picker

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try some thing like this hope it will help you

```
NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(this);
picker.setMinValue(1);
picker.setMaxValue(3);
picker.setDisplayedValues( new int[] { 2, 5, 10 } );
```

**Updated:**

You can retrieve the selected number using code below

```
String value = picker.getDisplayedValues()[picker.getValue()];
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks Mustanser for the pointer in the right direction. It's just important to note that setDisplayedValues takes a String array instead, so a functional answer would be:

```
NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(this);
picker.setMinValue(1);
picker.setMaxValue(3);
picker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "2", "5", "10" } );
```

Also, it is important to make sure you interpret the results of picker.getValue() correctly, since the underlying int values still run from 1 through 3:

```
int pick;
switch (picker.getValue()) {
  case 1:
    pick = 2;
    break;
  case 2:
    pick = 5;
    break;
  case 3:
    pick = 10;
    break;
  default:
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is the complete solution of the question

Comment: Why use switch option especially if you have many values instead you can just do something like this: `String value = numberPicker.getDisplayedValues()[i];` inside `setOnValueChangedListener`